# Ionic : popover from template > How to pass param URL dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have following code:

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover_available_sounds.html', {
            scope: $scope,
        }).then(function(popover) {
            $scope.popover = popover;
        });

        // Display Popover
        $scope.openPopover = function($event) {
            $scope.popover.show($event);
        };

        $scope.closePopover = function() {
            $scope.popover.hide();
        };
```

Which is called from view using:

```
<button ng-click="openPopover($event)"  
class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-circled"></button>
```

So i'm  not able to pass URL of the template  as param.

How can i do it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it using following code modification:

```
  // Display Popover
        $scope.openPopover = function($event, templateName) {
            // Init popover on load
            $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/'+templateName, {
                scope: $scope,
            }).then(function(popover) {
                $scope.popover = popover;
                $scope.popover.show($event);
            });
        };

        $scope.closePopover = function() {
            $scope.popover.hide();
        };
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to use a "controller as" syntax and figure out the ramifications of passing in a scope?